# how to perform scroll event via AccessibilityService when floating button is clicked in Android?

Tags: android, accessibility

I have a `Service` that initiate a `Button` and add it by calling `WindowManager.addView()`. this button is always showing on top of everything.

There's another `Service` that extends `AccessibilityService`. I do receive events in `onAccessibilityEvent`, but not click event happen on the `Button` created in another `Service`. I do receive click event on other views tho. another problem is how to trigger `onAccessibilityEvent` when user click on the `Button` that was created in another `Service`?

I have no idea why the `Button` created in `Service` doesn't fire `onAccessibilityEvent`.

here's my FloatingButton

```
public class FloatingButton extends Service {
    private WindowManager wm;
    private WindowManager.LayoutParams mButtonParams;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        mButtonParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        mButtonParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.START;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        startFloatingButton();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private void startFloatingButton() {
        Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setText("scroll");
        wm.addView(btn, mButtonParams);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // should fire onAccessibilityEvent() 
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and my `AccessibilityService`

```
public class MyAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService {
    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        Log.v(TAG, "event type: " + event.getEventType());
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {

    }
}
```

I need the `Button` created in FloatingButton `Service` either fire an event in `onAccessibilityEvent` or a way to perform `AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_SCROLL_FORWARD`. but without `AccessibilityEvent`, I don't know how to perform scroll action. and also, is there a way to check if the current view is scrollable before performing the action?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
mButtonParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

to

```
mButtonParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

and put it in `onServiceConnected()` method of your accessibility service. Create window manager in your accessibility service only then you can get accessibility event. For Scroll up and down,

```
nodeInfo.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_SCROLL_FORWARD);
nodeInfo.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_SCROLL_BACKWARD);
```

TYPE_PHONE didn't allow background clicks.